# KShell script skips commands when scheduled in cron

Tags: unix, script, cron, ksh

I have a Kshell script which executes a java program.

```
/path/to/java -jar jarfile.jar some parameters > log
Same line 5 times with different parameters appending output to log file.
cat log | mail -s email@email.com
```

The problem I keep having is when I put this script in cron only the last line which takes the log files & sends email is executed. All the above actual functionally required lines are ignored. I get a blank email on cron scheduled time, but the script should take around 1 hour.

But when I run the script manually, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the cron mails for problem. For "unable to access jarfile.jar" I added complete path in the script and for "cat: 0652-050 Cannot open /path/to/log", I created the log file before hand using touch command. Now my script looks like this.

```
touch /path/to/log
/path/to/java -jar /path/to/jarfile.jar some parameters > /path/to/log
Same line 5 times with different parameters appending output to log file.
cat /path/to/log | mail -s email@email.com
```

I came to know giving absolute path is the key to avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's the good old "cron with its very very simple environment" problem.
When you run your script in your own shell, the processes you start are in an environment that are set by your profiles.
However, your cron jobs start in a very basic environment, lacking a bunch of variables and path information. Actually, this can be guessed by looking in the mail cron sends about its runs or the global log of the cron daemon.

As you use ksh, I suggest sourcing .kshrc or .profile at the beginning of the script:

```
. /home/yourid/.kshrc
. /home/yourid/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks,I will keep this in mind, but I resolved the issue by giving full path for the jar file and log. I found the problem by looking at the cron mails.